# After upgrading to IntelliJ 2016.3 can no longer navigate to step definitions for gherkins/cucumber

Tags: intellij-idea, navigation, gherkin

Everything had been working great this morning.  I have upgraded to the newest IntelliJ version and everything still looks good, with the exception that I can no longer use 'ctrl+click' on steps in feature files.  Not sure what has changed; I've checked the dependencies and plugins and it all looks like it's there.  Did a restart as well, to no avail.  Just curious if anyone else might be seeing this with the upgrade?  I've checked JetBrains site with no luck as well.  It's happening for my other team members, too, after we each did the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this may be an actual bug according to their bug thread: youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164666

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same Problem. What fixed it for me was to setup IntelliJ as if I had no prior installation, when you first start it and it asks you if you want to import settings, don't.

There seems to be something in the old settings of IntelliJ 2016.2 that makes IntelliJ 2016.3 behave oddly.